# Get transaction hash using async/await promises NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I want to fetch the transaction hash by running this code:

```
const transactionId = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTransaction.toString('hex') ).on('receipt', function(receipt) {
    return receipt.transactionHash;
});

// Now it is known the transaction ID, so let's build the public Etherscan url where the transaction details can be viewed.
const url = `https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/${transactionId}`
console.log(url)
```

The code works for what concern the transactions, I can see them on Etherscan. The problem is about the JavaScript us of Promises.

I this case the console log outs:

```
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/[object Object]
```

I tried different ways to obtain the transaction hash with no success. Can you help me? It could also be the right opportunity to better understand how the Promises work.

Comment: Really, `on` returns a promise that can be awaited?

Comment: tried using `.then` and it works. 

Comment: Can you post the working version with `then` as well, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are combining promises with event emmiters ( which is possible ), but I would suggest trying first promise-based, after that event-emmiter based approach. Afterwards you could experiment with mixture. :)

1. promise based:

   ```
   async function fetch(){ const transactionID = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x'+serializedTransaction.toString('hex'));return transactionID; }let a = fetch() a.then(response=>console.log('transactionHash => ' + response)   .catch(error => console.log('error with sending transaction => ' + error);
   ```
2. event-emmiter based:

   > ```
   > const transactionID = web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x'+
   > serializedTransaction.toString('hex'))
   > .on('transactionHash',console.log) 
   > .on('receipt', console.log);
   > ```